# How do I make sure that everything I have previously deleted on a PC is unrecoverable?

Tags: windows, file-recovery, secure-erase

I'm thinking about giving an old Windows 7 PC away. In the past the PC stored private data and I have deleted those files.

What do I have to do to make sure that no data can be recovered?

Comment: ccleaner and Eraser for windows have free-space wipe features, that will securely destroy data on blocks not currently mapped to your filesystem.  that will securely wipe data created by allocating storage for a file, and then deleting it from the filesystem.

Comment: The simplest solution.  Boot to installation disk of Windows, delete all partition, install Windows.  At this point use Bitlocker or VeraCrypt and use full disk encryption.  The last step, boot to an installation disk of Windows and delete all partitions, and install Windows.  Turn off computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### If you have a mechanical drive

If your hard drive is a traditional rotating disk (i.e. not flash-based SSD), you can use the Microsoft SysInternals [Secure Delete](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/SDelete.zip) (SDelete) utility. According to the tool's [description](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete) page:

> The only way to ensure that deleted files, as well as files that you encrypt with EFS, are safe from recovery is to use a secure delete application. Secure delete applications overwrite a deleted file's on-disk data using techiques that are shown to make disk data unrecoverable, even using recovery technology that can read patterns in magnetic media that reveal weakly deleted files. SDelete (Secure Delete) is such an application.

SDelete is capable of securely erasing existing files, as well as free-space where data from previously-deleted files may still persist:

> You can use SDelete both to securely delete existing files, as well as to securely erase any file data that exists in the unallocated portions of a disk (including files that you have already deleted or encrypted).

It does this using DOD standards-based techniques:

> SDelete implements the Department of Defense clearing and sanitizing standard DOD 5220.22-M, to give you confidence that once deleted with SDelete, your file data is gone forever.

The one thing SDelete does/can *not* delete are filenames:

> Note that SDelete securely deletes file data, but not file names located in free disk space.

You can download SDelete [here](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/SDelete.zip).

#### Usage

To clear free space on drive C:, use the following:

```
sdelete -c C:
```

---

### If you have an SSD

Because of wear-leveling algorithms, it's basically impossible for software to access every sector of an SSD disk because the disk's controller software may randomly direct writes to different locations. Also, some SSDs may experience significant reduction in lifetime from a full disk wiping operation.

For these reasons, the best approach to clear an SSD is to use it's built-in Secure Erase feature (if supported). If such a feature isn't available, then it's not possible to guarantee erased data is irrecoverable and the drive should be physically destroyed to prevent data leak.

Answer (score 1):

Use CCleaner, they have an easy to use Wipe Free Space tool built in.

https://www.piriform.com/docs/ccleaner/using-ccleaner/wiping-free-disk-space

Comment: Link only answers are generally frowned upon. Can you expand your answer to summarize the linked document, or perhaps explore the wider context of the request?

Comment: CCleaner has been in the past compromised with malware.  It is unwise to suggest CCleaner at this time.  Avast as a company cannot be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic and puristic way to overwrite all unused disk space without any additional software is to fill it with dummy files. You have to do that once per partition in use. A cmd session (or a .bat file) could look like this:

```
c:
cd \
mkdir delete_this
cd delete_this
copy ANYFILE a
copy a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a b
copy b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b a
copy a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a b
copy b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b a
```

Now you have 10000 times the size of your file ANYFILE. continue the last two lines until file sysem is full, then delete a and b to free up disk space.

I know this is not the fastest way (because it reads the same disk it writes), it is sooo much last century style, it is not elegant (one-click). But it works, even if you can't just download a much nicer and smarter tool for any reason.

Comment: **This method cannot destroy all previously-deleted files.** For example, data for files <1KB in size is *only* stored in the MFT which occupies pre-allocated disk space this overwrite method cannot access.